# How can I make Internet Explorer show the standard right click link menu with a block level link?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Is there any way to make block level links show the standard link right click options, in particular "Save target as..."?

This is only an issue in Internet Explorer (mostly tested on IE9 on Win 7), all other browsers show the equivalent "save as..." option for all links.

In the following fiddle the block level links don't show the "Save target as..." option when right clicking on the text. When clicking on the image in the last example it works, but not when clicking on the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/CxUGL/3/

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 **compatibility view**, the menu is what you expect it to be. I read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/iewebdevelopment/thread/bb6d653c-40f7-46e3-83a0-406d96e23018#d13d9761-958f-4417-9b2a-5bd085f1d5f0) that it holds for IE9, too.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful to know. Unfortunately I'm using too many modern features to push IE into compatibility mode on my site.